# Why don't my OmniAuth callbacks update the page location during feature testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running into an issue where my OmniAuth callbacks seem to be operating correctly in production, but when feature testing the login links take me to the correct page BUT the current path is not updated.

Setup:

- Devise 4.2.0
- OmniAuth 1.3.1
- Rails 5.0.0.1
- Capybara 2.10.2

Replication:

In a feature example group with JS: true, put OmniAuth into test mode:

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = auth_hash
```

Construct the test

```
  context 'signing in' do
    it 'should operate correctly' do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t 'home.index.title')
      expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t 'home.index.text')
      page.find('.google-login').click
      wait_for_ajax
      # Fails here with:
      # expected "/users/auth/google_oauth2" to equal "/journal"
      expect(page).to have_current_path journal_root_path
    end
  end
```

When I inspect the page visually, the correct page has been rendered. What's happening? This doesn't seem to be a Capybara or Selenium problem; the browser correctly captures the (wrong) path.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was with Turbolinks.

It appears that when Turbolinks 5 is operating on that link, it snags the redirect. This is presumably because setting `OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true` tells OmniAuth to redirect to another page on the test server, whereas the production configuration sends the link to the Facebook servers.

In the test scenario, Turbolinks intercepts it because its on the same server, but in production Turbolinks does NOT intercept the link.

The solution was to update my social media link tags with a `data-turbolinks="false"` attribute. from:

```
          <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
              <%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{(provider_name provider).downcase}-login social-login-small" do %>
                  <i></i> <%= provider_name provider %> Login
              <% end %>
          <% end -%>
```

to:

```
          <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
              <%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{(provider_name provider).downcase}-login social-login-small", data: {turbolinks: false} do %>
                  <i></i> <%= provider_name provider %> Login
              <% end %>
          <% end -%>
```